# abind error - arg 'XXX' has dims=1912, 35, 1; but need dims=0, 35, X

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use `abind` to create a 3-D array out of a large 2D array. The source data is structured  like this

```
Firstname   Lastname    Country City    Measure Wk1 Wk2... Wkn
foo            bar        UK    London  Height  23   34    34
foo            bar        UK    London  Weight  67  67     67
foo           bar         UK    London  Fat     6   7      9
John          doe         US    NY      Height  546 776   978
John          doe         US    NY      Weight  123 656   989
John          doe         US    NY      Fat     34  45    67
```

There are 1912 rows per Measure and 25 weeks of data. I am trying to create a 3D array such that I can measure city wise trends of the Measures - height weight etc.

When I use `abind(split(df,df$city), along =3)`, it gives me the error:

```
abind error - arg 'XXX' has dims=1912, 35, 1; but need dims=0, 35, X
```

I have verified that the number of rows are 1912 per measure and the number of columns are also homogenous. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that all elements of `split(df, df$City)` must have identical dimensions.

Comment: With the sample of df you gave, it works...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to use arrays to measure city trends?

Usually the right approach to analysing data like yours is to unpivot the weeks into `long` format.

I'll start by importing your data into R...

```
tc <- textConnection("Firstname   Lastname    Country City    Measure Wk1 Wk2 Wk3
foo            bar        UK    London  Height  23   34    34
foo            bar        UK    London  Weight  67  67     67
foo           bar         UK    London  Fat     6   7      9
John          doe         US    NY      Height  546 776   978
John          doe         US    NY      Weight  123 656   989
John          doe         US    NY      Fat     34  45    67")


df <- read.table(tc, header = TRUE)
```

Then install and load a couple of useful packages.

```
install.packages("tidyr")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

Now to unpivot your data using the `gather` command from `tidyr`.

```
> long_df <- gather(df, Week, Value, -c(1:5)) 
> long_df
   Firstname Lastname Country   City Measure Week Value
1        foo      bar      UK London  Height  Wk1    23
2        foo      bar      UK London  Weight  Wk1    67
3        foo      bar      UK London     Fat  Wk1     6
4       John      doe      US     NY  Height  Wk1   546
5       John      doe      US     NY  Weight  Wk1   123
6       John      doe      US     NY     Fat  Wk1    34
7        foo      bar      UK London  Height  Wk2    34
8        foo      bar      UK London  Weight  Wk2    67
9        foo      bar      UK London     Fat  Wk2     7
10      John      doe      US     NY  Height  Wk2   776
11      John      doe      US     NY  Weight  Wk2   656
12      John      doe      US     NY     Fat  Wk2    45
13       foo      bar      UK London  Height  Wk3    34
14       foo      bar      UK London  Weight  Wk3    67
15       foo      bar      UK London     Fat  Wk3     9
16      John      doe      US     NY  Height  Wk3   978
17      John      doe      US     NY  Weight  Wk3   989
18      John      doe      US     NY     Fat  Wk3    67
```

Now you can use `dplyr` to produce any summaries of the data that you please...

```
> long_df %>% 
+   group_by(Country, City, Measure) %>% 
+   summarise(mean_val = mean(Value))
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: Country, City

  Country   City Measure   mean_val
1      UK London     Fat   7.333333
2      UK London  Height  30.333333
3      UK London  Weight  67.000000
4      US     NY     Fat  48.666667
5      US     NY  Height 766.666667
6      US     NY  Weight 589.333333
```

Or summaries by Country and Measure...

```
> long_df %>% 
+   group_by(Country,  Measure) %>% 
+   summarise(mean_val = mean(Value), med_val = median(Value), count = n())
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: Country

  Country Measure   mean_val med_val count
1      UK     Fat   7.333333       7     3
2      UK  Height  30.333333      34     3
3      UK  Weight  67.000000      67     3
4      US     Fat  48.666667      45     3
5      US  Height 766.666667     776     3
6      US  Weight 589.333333     656     3
```